# loop within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to write a loop within a loop in R, but it seems only the inner loop is working:

```
test <- rbind(c(1:30), c(31:60), c(61:90), c(91:120))
```

Here's what I've been written:

```
b<- data.frame()
n<-1
i<-1
c<- data.frame()

while(i<=4){
    while(n<=10) {
        a<-cbind(test[i, 3*n-2], test[i, 3*n-1], test[i,3*n])
        b<-rbind(b,a); n<-n+1
    } ; i<-i+1; c<-cbind(c,b)
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to group each line by three columns and transform it into multiple lines, and then do it to every line and bind these columns.

My desired output would look like:

```
   1  2  3  31  32  33  61  62  63  81  82  83
   4  5  6  34  35  36  64  65  66  84  85  86
   7  8  9  37  38  39  67  68  69  ......
  10 11 12  40  41  42  ......
  13 14 15  43  45  46
  16 17 18 ......
  19 20 21
  22 23 24
  25 26 27
  28 29 30  58  59  60  78  79  80  118 119 120
```

However what I have written only work for the first line, apparently the outer loop doesn't work. What's wrong with it please?

edit:
Here's what I further tried in response to the for loop:

```
b<- data.frame()
c<- data.frame()
for(i in seq(from = 1, to = 4, by =1)){
    for( n in seq(from=1, to=10, by=1)) {
        a <- cbind(test[i, 3*n-2], test[i, 3*n-1], test[i,3*n])
        b <- rbind(b,a)
    }
        c <- cbind(c,b)
}
```

But I still could not make it work. what's wrong with it?

Comment: Why dont you use for loops? Might make your code easier to read....

Comment: You need to reset `n` in the outer loop after your inner `while` statement. As-is, when `i` is 1, `n` get's incremented up to 11, and then when `i` is 2 `n` is still 11 and the inner loop is never entered. Using `for` loops as Dennis suggests will help prevent bugs like this.

Comment: Could you show me how you do with the for loop? I couldn't make it to work..

Comment: IS there some reason you *have* to use `for` loops? Surely the approach I demonstrate below is easier? `lapply` is actually a looping construct. It loops along each column of the transposed matrix `test` (which I coerced to a `data.frame` to make this work) and reshapes each column into a matrix of the correct dimensions. The `do.call` `cbind`s the resulting smaller matrices together.

Comment: @user1687130 I have edited the answer to include a for loop.

Comment: @SimonO101 Thank you for the answers and clear explanations! I do like your easier method. I'm fairly new to R so the loops were something quickly come to my mind to solve this problem, and it was frustrating when it didn't work, but it's great the learn the lapply function in R. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might make your life a bit easier...

```
out <- lapply( data.frame( t(test) ) , matrix , ncol = 3 , byrow = TRUE )
res <- do.call( cbind , out )
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    1    2    3   31   32   33   61   62   63    91    92    93
 [2,]    4    5    6   34   35   36   64   65   66    94    95    96
 [3,]    7    8    9   37   38   39   67   68   69    97    98    99
 [4,]   10   11   12   40   41   42   70   71   72   100   101   102
 [5,]   13   14   15   43   44   45   73   74   75   103   104   105
 [6,]   16   17   18   46   47   48   76   77   78   106   107   108
 [7,]   19   20   21   49   50   51   79   80   81   109   110   111
 [8,]   22   23   24   52   53   54   82   83   84   112   113   114
 [9,]   25   26   27   55   56   57   85   86   87   115   116   117
[10,]   28   29   30   58   59   60   88   89   90   118   119   120
```

Possibly even slightly easier would be to do...

```
do.call( cbind , lapply( 1:4 , function(x) matrix( test[x,] , ncol = 3 , byrow = F ) ) )
```

If you *insist* on using a `for` loop this is probably the easiest way...

```
out <- numeric()
for( i in 1:4 ){
  tmp <- matrix( test[ i , ] , ncol = 3 , byrow = TRUE )
  out <- cbind( out , tmp )
  }
```

The problem stemmed from your use of `out <- data.frame` to initialise the result data structure. It meant you were trying to `cbind` a `data.frame` with no rows to one with 10 rows. Not possible (although intuitively being able to `cbind` an empty vector with a 10 row `matrix` should probably fail too but it doesnt!).

Comment: Thanks! Although I'm still struggling with the loops, this definitely makes life easier!:)